# Javascript countdown to appear multiple times?

Tags: javascript, counter

I am just learning html and css, and want to add javascript code that I found on here. This code basicly counts down from specific minute or second.

Here is the code:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
      minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 28.4,
      display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

How could I use this code multiple times? With different time settings. All on same page ofcourse.

I have this code in countdown.js file, and it works great. But If I try to make "countdown2.js" etc, and use that, it wont work. I changed "#time" in code to "time2" etc, and did same in html code.

Sorry for bad explanation. I dont realy know javascript yet, as I havent started learning it quite yet. But I realy need countdown on my site to appear 5 times, each time with different time settings. And I can only display it once.

Comment: I need to know exactly what you are going to do. Do you need the 5 clocks to do the exact same thing, or are you gonna make any of them behave in a different way?

Comment: Each clock will have different countdown timer. All on same page tho.

Comment: The code you posted is already prepared for multiple timers. e.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/1ng3scv1/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.onload = function () {
  var timer1 = 60 * 28.4,
  display1 = document.querySelector('#time1');
  startTimer(timer1, display1);
  var timer2 = 60 * 28.5,
  display2 = document.querySelector('#time2');
  startTimer(timer2, display2); 
//... Continues
};
```

The output will be shown in tags with ids time1 and time2 respectively.